# join condition depends on the parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm a sql newbie, I use mssql2005

I like to do join Action depnding on input parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectPeriodicLargeCategoryData 
    @CATEGORY_LEVEL CHAR(1),
    @CATEGORY_CODE VARCHAR(9)
AS

...


JOIN CATEGORY_AD_SYS CAS WITH(NOLOCK)
ON CA.CATEGORY_ID = [[[[[   HERE      ]]]]
```

above the sql.
if `@CATEGORY_LEVEL = 'L'` then I like to join on  `CAS.LCATEGORY`

else if `@CATEGORY_LEVEL = 'M'` then I like to join on  `CAS.MCATEGORY`

else if `@CATEGORY_LEVEL = 'S'` then I like to join on  `CAS.SCATEGORY`

...

how can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `CASE` expression such as:

```
CASE @CATEGORY_LEVEL  
     WHEN 'L' THEN CAS.LCATEGORY
     WHEN 'M' THEN CAS.MCATEGORY
     WHEN 'S' THEN CAS.SCATEGORY
END
```

I'm not sure how fast that would be in a `JOIN`'s `ON` condition (depends on how smart the query optimizer is about it, of course, so you'd better check by measuring with real data) -- if it turns out to have unacceptable performance, I guess you could use completely different `SELECT` statements depending on `@CATEGORY_LEVEL` as a last resort.

Answer (score 2):

This would be easier if you normalized your tables into [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).  Right now your different category columns form a *repeating group*.

To accomplish this normalization, you need another table to represent the many-to-many relationship between `CAS` and `CA`.

```
CREATE TABLE HasCategory (
  CATEGORY_ID    INTEGER,
  CAS_ID         INTEGER,
  CATEGORY_LEVEL CHAR(1), -- 'L' or 'M' or 'S'
  PRIMARY KEY (CATEGORY_ID, CAS_ID, CATEGORY_LEVEL),
  FOREIGN KEY (CATEGORY_ID) REFERENCES CATEGORIES,
  FOREIGN KEY (CAS_ID) REFERENCES CATEGORY_AD_SYS
);
```

Then you can write your join conditions in a much more straightforward way:

```
SELECT ...
FROM CATEGORIES CA
JOIN HasCategory H ON (H.CATEGORY_ID = CA.CATEGORY_ID)
JOIN CATEGORY_AD_SYS CAS ON (H.CAS_ID = CAS.CAS_ID)
WHERE H.CATEGORY_LEVEL = @CATEGORY_LEVEL
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't fix the schema as Bill Karwin said, then use IF to switch queries.

Using a CASE statement will kill performance (I assume you gave indexes on the columns)

```
IF @CATEGORY_LEVEL = 'L'
    SELECT
    ...
    JOIN CATEGORY_AD_SYS CAS WITH(NOLOCK) ON CA.CATEGORY_ID = CAS.LCATEGORY

ELSE IF @CATEGORY_LEVEL = 'M'
    SELECT
    ...
    JOIN CATEGORY_AD_SYS CAS WITH(NOLOCK) ON CA.CATEGORY_ID = CAS.MCATEGORY 

ELSE IF @CATEGORY_LEVEL = 'M'
    SELECT
    ...
    JOIN CATEGORY_AD_SYS CAS WITH(NOLOCK) ON CA.CATEGORY_ID = CAS.SCATEGORY
```

Comment: THE SELECT STATEMENT is very long.. so i just want to change  join on condition depending on input parameter

Comment: If it's very long, then it means CASE will perform worse. It's 3 different JOINs so it is 3 different SELECTs